# Prevent blank links (having javascript:;) from openening in new tab/window on middle click...?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sliding-doors

There is a common practice of using **`<a></a>`** tags to markup beautiful buttons, with onlick and onhover style change, etc. Which looks and behaves great, on most part.

Although there turned out to be a HUGE problem, which was not very obvious on start. The problem is that these beautiful "buttons" open new windows on middle click, either blank or with the same content as current one (depends on whether one uses # or javascript:; to disable href part).

Now I've got JavaScript RIA with buttons all over it, opening new windows on middle click... Lame...

At first I even couldn't understand why I get sometimes those blank pages in the browser.

Since it's pretty established practice to use links in such manner, maybe there is any established way to deal with described problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What I did in the end, was that I replaced all `<a>...</a>` tags with `<span>...</span>`s. The only problem with this is that IE doesn't support :active on spans, so I do not really get interactive buttons anymore in IE.

Comment: ... and people can't focus on the links using a keyboard, a TV remote control or a breath switch or access the "links" by using the "read me all the links in this document" features of most screen readers. This is a horrible, inaccessible hack to work around side effects of an ugly corner cutting technique.

Comment: Well, they were not exactly meant to be links at all. I guess you never understood the problem really.

Comment: If we say "Control the user has to interact with" instead of "Link" then the same problems apply.

Comment: I think at some point I will replace them with styled buttons and the odyssey will end there.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a function to the link, which returns false. For example:

```
<a href="javascript: return false">Not clickable</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't have `href="javascript:…"` in the first place, [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

Comment: I agree, but that's not a case with RIA, which should not go anywhere and just stay where it is and work without reload.

Comment: Ah, "Rich" is code for "cutting corners and then suffering from blank pages when people interact with it as if it was a web app" is it?

Comment: :D yeah, kinda. But it was not meant to create blank pages :)